# git: replace folder with the same folder on a different branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I tried

```
git checkout OTHER_BRANCH -- /path/to/folder
```

the problem is with files that exist on current branch, but do not exist on the other branch.
I want to delete these.

Comment: from what I understood all you need is git rm. But the question is a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think you want:

```
git rm -r /path/to/folder
git checkout OTHER_BRANCH -- /path/to/folder
```

Comment: it may be necessary to run the first command with the "-f" flag, to force the deletion of uncommited changes, too.